# No nc arguments being recognized

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, netcat

I'm having trouble using my `nc` command. Everytime I enter any parameter, even using `-h`, linux just prints:

```
*BusyBox v1.20.2 (2014-05-14 13:19:21 EDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [IPADDR PORT]*
```

I am able to type `nc localhost 22`  which produces

```
*SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6*
```

Not to sure what's going on...

Comment: It seems to be working. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: What do you expect it should output?

Comment: I want to be able to use options such as -l listen and -D for debug etc... But everytime i feed in a option it won't allow it. Because it says 
Usage: nc [IPADDR PORT]

I essentially want to be able to use parameters with nc. Do I have to install additional packages? or change a configuration file for this?

Comment: I'm trying to set up udp in a ssh tunnel using this tutorial:
[link](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html)

At one point i need to use the nc command in such a way as:
local# sudo nc -l -u -p 53 < /tmp/fifo | nc localhost 6667 > /tmp/fifo

but my nc doesn't allow parameters...

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely working on an embedded system where many tools are only available in a limited form in the form of [`busybox`](http://www.busybox.net/). This tool collection only offer the most essential features, and it's entirely possible the `nc` features you want are not available.

Modern OpenSSH versions don't need `nc` for a tunnel. Look into the `-W` parameter.

Adapted from my `~/.ssh/config` files:

```
Host  *.example.com !gateway.example.com
   ProxyCommand ssh -q -A  -x gateway.example.com -W %h:%p
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Not sure if this works for your specific case though.

Comment: Is there a way to include more features to a tool in this case?

Comment: @sphchow: Depends on your environment. See my edit for a better way to create a tunnel.

Comment: The reason I need to do it with nc is because it lets me setup TCP to UDP forward on my server. So I don't think your way to create a tunnel will work for my purpose? I'm not an expert so I definitely could be missing something.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw the UDP part and I am not sure it will work right, I use this for a SSH gateway host.

Comment: @sphchow Why are you trying to do any of this at all?

Comment: No need to be sorry! Your comments helped me out. Hopefully I can give @Iain answer a try and that will enable all the capabilities I need.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to do this in short is...

I have one program on my localhost and another program on Lets say Host B communicating to each other. Host A is in between, therefore I need to create a tunnel from local to B. The data is in UDP so I need to foward the SSH Port to a UDP port so the programs can process it on the local side and host B side. 
Hopefully that makes sense?
(Sorry I don't know how to tag you Michael)

Comment: If you know a better way to do this, that'd be awesome. So far the only way I could find was using this:
http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html

Comment: @sphchow Eh? What's wrong with using a VPN like everyone else?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm pretty new at this... what are the benefits of using VPN instead of the method I'm trying to implement right now? I'm not to familar with VPN so I wouldn't know how to implement it. Giving it a quick read it seems I have to install additional packages and do a bit of configuring. Also apparantly using UDP for VPN for long distances is a bad idea?

Comment: @sphchow You still haven't explained why you are trying to do this.

Comment: I guess I'm confused to what you refer to when you are saying what I'm trying to do. 

Why I need more nc options or why do I need UDP two way tunneling?


I need nc options to have the ability to forward data entering a TCP port to a UDP port.


And I need UDP two way tunneling because the two programs that talk to each other do so in UDP.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your version of busybox nc has been compiled without listening capability. There is a compile time option `NC_SERVER` that has to be set to get the capabilities you want. The messages and functionality ou are seeing are entirely consistent with this being not set.